How to remove metal shower door sweep holder that is siliconed on to bottom of the door?
My (3/8") glass shower door sweep needs replacing as the dangling flap that forms the seal has mostly broken away.
In my case it seems the sweep is designed to go into a groove in the bottom of a metal frame that is siliconed onto the door (see image in link below). But there is so much calcification in that area from the hard water that there is no way I could easily remove that remaining piece in the groove (and in any case I have not seen anything for sale that would fit that).
So my thinking was to remove that metal frame and replace with a simple full plastic sweep (like this one).
My question is what is the easiest and safest way to remove that existing metal frame that is attached with silicone? (Or is there some other solution I should be considering?)

IMAGE: https://imgur.com/a/10BUml8

please add the picture directly into the question, instead of a link ... use the button that looks like the mountains and the sun

Cut the silicone with utility knife.
Remove the metal frame and give it a good clean so you can reuse it.
Replace the sweep and mount the frame with silicone.
Optional:
Keep a spray bottle with vinegar in the bathroom to prevent that ugly looking calc deposit on the glass. Or use silicone squeegee

Or get a silicone squeegee and wipe down the door after each use.
